# fade in button so it won't automatically fade out again

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button, timer

I'm using a tap gesture recogniser so if the user taps on the screen the button fades out for 5 seconds and then if the user wants to see the buttons on the screen again they tap on the screen and the button fades in.

The Problem is:

I can't disable the button when it fades in so it won't automatically fade out again. I tried to invalidate the timer but that didn't work. To be more specific of what I want to do:

On app load, you see an enabled "Start Stop Button." - Tap anywhere on the screen and a 5 second timer starts to fade the button out and disables it. Once the button fades out and disables, I can tap anywhere on the screen to fade the button back in, enable it, and kill the timer so the button shows up as it was before I first tapped it.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Create these 3 properties in the top of your class
    var secondToFadeOut = 5 // How many second do you want the view to idle before the button fades. You can change this to whatever you'd like.
    var timer = Timer() // Create the timer!
    var isTimerRunning: Bool = false // Need this to prevent multiple timers from running at the same time.


@IBOutlet weak var startStopButton: UIButton! // The outlet for your button. This is used to fade it in and out, and enable / disable it.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startStopButton.isEnabled = true
    runTimer()

    // Add a tap gesture recognizer to the main view to determine when the screen was tapped (for the purpose of resetting the timer).
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

}

func runTimer() {
    // Create the timer to run a method (in this case... updateTimer) every 1 second.
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Set the isTimerRunning bool to true
    isTimerRunning = true
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    // Every 1 second that this method runs, 1 second will be chopped off the secondToFadeOut property. If that hits 0 (< 1), then run the fadeOutButton and invalidate the timer so it stops running.
    secondToFadeOut -= 1
    print(secondToFadeOut)
    if secondToFadeOut < 1 {
        fadeOutButton()
        timer.invalidate()
        isTimerRunning = false
    }
}

@objc func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // When the view is tapped (based on the gesture recognizer), reset the secondToFadeOut property, fade in (and enable) the button.
    //secondToFadeOut = 5
    fadeInButton()
    timer.invalidate()
    //if isTimerRunning == false {
    //    runTimer()
    //}
}

func fadeOutButton() {
    // Fade out your button! I also disabled it here. But you can do whatever your little heart desires.
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.startStopButton.alpha = 0.25
    }
    self.startStopButton.isEnabled = false
}
func fadeInButton() {
    // Fade the button back in, and set it back to active (so it's tappable)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.startStopButton.alpha = 1
    }
    self.startStopButton.isEnabled = true
}


@IBAction func startStopButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Start Stop Button Pressed")
}
}
```

Comment: Why can't you disable the button when it fades in? (Seeing this relatively large amount of code, I get the feeling you're making things more complicated than necessary.)

Comment: Why don't you just hide button with animation, instead playing with alpha property?

Comment: To go along with the above (^^^) comment, animating the `isHidden` property should mean you won't need to enable/disable.

Comment: I've tried that but when the button fades in it, it still automatically fades out again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you have a rogue `Timer` object that remains in memory even after you invalidate your current timer, and that is causing the button to fade out again after it fades in.

I have made several edits to your class. Check the code out:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
// Create these 3 properties in the top of your class
var secondToFadeOut = 5 // How many second do you want the view to idle before the button fades. You can change this to whatever you'd like.
var timer? = nil // Create the timer!

@IBOutlet weak var startStopButton: UIButton! // The outlet for your button. This is used to fade it in and out, and enable / disable it.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startStopButton.isEnabled = true
    runTimer()

    // Add a tap gesture recognizer to the main view to determine when the screen was tapped (for the purpose of resetting the timer).
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

func runTimer() {
    if timer == nil {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: secondToFadeOut, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.timerFired)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

@objc func timerFired() {
    timer = nil
    if self.startStopButton.isEnabled {
        fadeOutButton()
    } else {
        fadeInButton()
    }
}

@objc func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    runTimer()
}

func fadeOutButton() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.startStopButton.alpha = 0.25
    }
    self.startStopButton.isEnabled = false
}

func fadeInButton() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.startStopButton.alpha = 1
    }
    self.startStopButton.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func startStopButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Start Stop Button Pressed")
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it says ''nil' requires a contextual type' do you know what thids means?

Comment: Try `var timer: Timer? = nil`, it needs to know what type `timer` is.

Comment: Thanks, it disappears and reappears now without automatically fading out again but now the tap is disabled so it won't let me tap on the screen again.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? I assumed you want this: Button shows in beginning -> wait 5 seconds -> Button Fades -> Tap screen -> Button Shows (and never fades). So after you are at the last step, the tap on the screen should do nothing because the button is already visible. If that is not what you want, please explain your exact sequence of events that you want.

Comment: Button shows in beginning -> Tap Screen and wait 5 seconds -> Button Fades Out -> Tap screen and wait 5 seconds -> Button Fades In and then repeat the same sequence again if the user taps on the screen.

Comment: In your comment your last steps are: " Button Fades -> Tap screen and wait 5 seconds -> Button Fades". How can the button fade if it is already faded? It has to show somewhere in between for it to fade.

Comment: Sorry what I mean't was this: beginning -> Tap Screen and wait 5 seconds -> Button Fades Out -> Tap screen and wait 5 seconds -> Button reappears and then repeat the same sequence again if the user taps on the screen.